# mongodb Aggregation query unable to create

Tags: mongodb

```
Hello all i have different document containing "category" field i have to get result from aggregation query to find number of document in each category and find result in array which sould contain {_id and num } field;


    {
       "_id": NumberInt(23),
       "title": "WiredTiger T-shirt",
       "slogan": "Unleash the tiger",
       "description": "Crafted from ultra-soft combed cotton, this essential t-shirt features sporty contrast tipping and MongoDB's signature leaf.",
       "stars": NumberInt(0),
       "category": "Apparel",
       "img_url": "/img/products/wt-shirt.jpg",
       "price": 22 
    }


    {
       "_id": NumberInt(22),
       "title": "Water Bottle",
       "slogan": "Glass water bottle",
       "description": "High quality glass bottle provides a healthier way to drink. Silicone sleeve provides a good grip, a see-through window, and protects the glass vesse [...]",
       "stars": NumberInt(0),
       "category": "Kitchen",
       "img_url": "/img/products/water-bottle.jpg",
       "price": 23 
    }
```

i have many documents like this.
I have used the below query:-

db.collectionname.find({category:"categoryname"},{_id:1}).count(); 
but in this stage i will only get one category data.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort....

Comment: Hello Alex I am new in mongoDB and sorry for not mentioning i have tried db.collectionname.find({category:"categoryname"},{_id:1}).count(); but in this stage i will only get one category data

Comment: how can i get desired result?if you know please help me.

Comment: It is nowhere close to aggregation. Also, it is much better to add code snippets to the question, rather than comments.

Comment: I am new in aggregation and only know about basic queries.

Comment: Then it may worth to read https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/ first, and probably http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use group for this query. For group you have to use aggreagetion in mongodb. The following will do what you want:

`db.collection.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$category", num: {$sum: 1}}}]);`

The mongodb documentation also has an example:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/count/